# Hide tooltip when mouse leave in two different blocks

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, events, mouseleave

I have a tooltip that I need to hide when the cursor leaves it. But the problem is that the user may not point at him, so I need to remove the tooltip even when the cursor is removed from the block where the tooltip appears.

Another problem is that if one of the blocks is allowed to hide the tooltip when leaving it, then when switching to another block the tooltip will close.

I try with onMouseLeave={() => {}} maybe another ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Can u plz send the code?

Comment: Why dont you try this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip. It helps you a lot!